# animate text in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, styles

I'm trying to animate text in React by using scss (probably it doesn't matter). It doesn't work.

In SCSS file:

```
.animate {
    animation: 3s linear 1s infinite alternate slidein;
}
```

Aplied on my text:

```
<h2 className="animate">Order is active.</h2>
```

Should I do something more?
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use marquee:

```
<marquee behavior="slide" direction="down">Order is active.</marquee>
```

**For more attributes: https://www.w3schools.in/html-tutorial/marquee-tag/**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use animation with @keyframe. @keyframe specifies what to do, animation when and how
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2.

Or you can use "transition" with additional class name
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Somethin like this:

```
#scss
.main-class {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: 1s;
}
.hide-classname {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: 1s;
}

#jsx \ tsx
const [hide, setHide] = useState(false)

return(
    <div className={`main-class ${hide ? 'hide-classname' : null}`}>
         i will disappear
    </div>
)
```

Comment: @SweetCaramel, sometimes animation can be broken into react if a rerender is executed between states (actually i don't know exactly how to break the animation. only imho). Transition animation does not work if there is no initial state (animations always need a style from which to transition to another style)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle any kind of animation like low level to high level animation using this npm package built for react. `react-transition-group`.
`mountOnEnter` is one of the future available in it. which mount the component and start animate based on Boolean condition.
These animation states be will handled in class prefix from css followes.

- entering
- entered
- exiting
- exited

all kind of animation possibilities which are done in `animate.css` can be handled in above states.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to checkout [react-animated-text-builders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-text-builders). It's a small lib that supports some text animations. Nothing fancy, but  maybe those animations are sufficient for your purposes:

```
<FloatingLettersTextBuilder
        floatingSpeed={500}
        lettersAppearanceDelay={250}
      > Floating Letters 
</FloatingLettersTextBuilder>
```

This will slide the text in from right to left.

[image: gif]